# how to remove report header part in SSRS drildown mobile report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

i have .NET application where i have iframe and i am loading SSRS drildown mobile report URL into iframe and it's working but when i moving to 2nd lavel of drildown report it's loading report but report header apears which i don't want to show to the user.

i am using below URL to load drildown report

iframe.scr = "http://Desktop-1213/SSRSReports/mobilereport/MainReport?rs:Embed=true";

[image: SSRS Report Image]

want to remove the hignlighed in red color one.

another way i have tried, used rs:Embed=true in  dripthrough custum URL option but it's opening in different window. but i want in same window.

let me know if need more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation here and search for `rv:HeaderArea`. It may lead to a workable solution. I would also be curious what `rc:toolbar=false` would look like in your situation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference

If all else fails you can retrieve the raw report as html40 directly form the api, however, most of the navigational features will have to be re-implemented.

Comment: rc:toolbar=false/true  is not working, header is displaying if set rs:Embed=true , if i set rs:Embed=false report is not loading in iframe. may in know without passing  rs:Embed why mobile report not loading in iFrame